# read.table unable to read tab delimited file?

Tags: r

I'm having trouble reading this table into R:

http://www.census.gov/popest/about/geo/state_geocodes_v2012.txt

I tried all of the following:

```
read.table("http://www.census.gov/popest/about/geo/state_geocodes_v2012.txt")
read.table("http://www.census.gov/popest/about/geo/state_geocodes_v2012.txt",skip=7,header=FALSE)
read.table("http://www.census.gov/popest/about/geo/state_geocodes_v2012.txt",skip=8,header=FALSE)
read.table("http://www.census.gov/popest/about/geo/state_geocodes_v2012.txt",skip=10,header=FALSE)
```

If I tell it that the separator is a tab, i get the wrong table:

```
d = read.table(file="http://www.census.gov/popest/about/geo/state_geocodes_v2012.txt",header=FALSE,skip=7,sep="\t")
```

the only thing that seems to work is readLines. but then i don't know how to get a data.frame out of each line.

```
d =readLines("http://www.census.gov/popest/about/geo/state_geocodes_v2012.txt")
```

any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: looks more like a fixed width doc `?read.fwf`

Comment: yep, try `read.fwf("state_geocodes_v2012.txt", skip=7, widths=c(8, 8, 8, 20))` if you can live without the header.

Comment: If you want to have the names: `geocodes <- read.fwf("~/Downloads/state_geocodes_v2012.txt", c(8,8,8,40), skip=7)
names(geocodes) <- c("Region","Division", "State (FIPS)", "Name")`

Answer (score 1):

I agree that `read.fwf`  will work, once you've worked out the widths.

But, Yeah -- I just **hate** people who allow whitespace inside elements (e.g. "SouthDakota" )  . One other thing you can do is edit the source text file, replacing {2,N} spaces with a tab. That will leave the state names as-is but give you a workable delimiter.